# Rounded corners in highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have graph like this http://jsfiddle.net/developer_fiddle/6VKtb/

I want to get the rounded corners in this graph but I am unable to do so probable because I have used plotbands here .
Is it possible to have rounded corners in this graph?
Also is there any option available to move the circle marker little below the bar.

**Relevant Code**

```
function drawGraph(point,container)
   {
      Highcharts.setOptions({
            chart:{
                type:'bar',
                margin:[15,15,35,15],
                plotBorderWidth: 1,
                plotBorderColor: '#999',
            },
            credits:{enabled:false},
            legend:{enabled:false},
            title:{text:''},
            xAxis:{
                tickLength:0,
                lineWidth:0,
                labels: ""      
            },
            yAxis:{
                min:1,
                tickColor:'#888',
                tickWidth:2,
                tickLength:6,
                tickInterval:1,
                minorTickInterval:5,
                minorTickWidth:2,
                minorTickLength:4,
                minorGridLineWidth:0,
                tickPosition: 'outside',
                gridLineWidth:1,
                endOnTick:false,
            },

            plotOptions:{
                    series: {
                        animation: false,          
                     },
                bar:{
                        borderRadius:10,  
                    },
                scatter:{
                      animation:false,
                      marker:{ 
                         radius:'15',
                         fillColor : '#F00',
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart:{renderTo:container},
            xAxis:{max:1},
            yAxis:{
                  title:{ 
                     text:'',
                  },
                max:10,
                labels:{y:20,style:{fontSize:'11px'}},    
                plotBands:[{from:1,to:1.5,color: 'rgba(214,69,41,.3)'},
                           {from:1.5,to:3.5,color:'rgba(240,168,57,.3)'},
                           {from:3.5,to:5,color: 'rgba(209,218,85,.3)'},
                           {from:5,to:6,color: 'rgba(166,199,111,.3)'},
                           {from:6,to:7.5,color: 'rgba(130,182,69,.3)'},
                           {from:7.5,to:9.5,color: 'rgba(106,150,49,.3)'},
                           {from:9.5,to:10,color: 'rgba(82,121,44,.3)',outerRadius: '105'}]
            },
            series:[
                {name:'Target',type: 'scatter',data:[[0,0]]}]
        });
        point = parseInt(point);
        chart1.series[0].points[0].update({x:0,y:point}, true, {duration: 1000});
   }
```

[image]

Comment: The plotbands should be rounded only or entire chart? In second scenarion how about labels, have you a mockup of your concept?

Comment: @SebastianBochan I want extreme plotbands to be rounded .see image in question

Answer (score 3):

How about using bar chart with `stacking` set to `normal` and plugin for rounded corners? Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/2TuCW/67/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'bar'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            stacking: 'normal'   
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        endOnTick: false,
        maxPadding: 0
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9],
        // usage:
        borderRadiusTopLeft: 25,
        borderRadiusTopRight: 25
    }, {
        data: [29.9]
    }, {
        data: [29.9]
    }, {
        data: [29.9]
    }, {
        data: [29.9],
        borderRadiusBottomRight: 25,
        borderRadiusBottomLeft: 25
    }]

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a plotBorderRadius setting, per the docs, and per experiment.

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart

There is a chartBorderRadius, but that will only help you if you make the plot fill the entire chart area, which means your marker could not extend beyond the plot area as it does now.

In your current code, you are not displaying any setting for round corners, except on the 'bar' series type, but I do not see a bar series in your data.  The settings for the bar type will not apply to plotBands, or to any other element.

I would guess your two options are

1) make the plot fill the entire chart area by setting all margins and spacing to 0, 
or
2) find some sort of complex svg code to draw it manually